# Partial fraction decomposition for complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I'm trying to find the partial fraction decomposition of the complex function
$\frac{1}{z(z+1/2)(z-2)} $.

So I have that 
$\frac{1}{z(z+1/2)(z-2)} = \frac{A}{z} + \frac{B}{z+1/2} + \frac{C}{z-2}$,
where

$\ 1= A(z+1/2)(z-2) + B(z)(z-2) + C(z)(z+1/2)$,
which is equivalent to

$\ 1= z^2(A+B+C) + z (\frac{-3}{2}A -2B + \frac{1}{2}C) - A$ .

But here is where I am confused. How do I solve for the A, B, C values when these can be complex? I thought that we could just set

$\ A+B+C = 0$,

$\frac{-3}{2}A -2B + \frac{1}{2}C = 0$, and

$\ -A = 1$,

since none of the z-terms appear on the left-hand side of the equation, but I don't think this is right since z and A, B, C are complex numbers. So how do I go about solving this? How do I take into account both the real and imaginary parts to solve for A, B and C?

Comment: What you have is correct.  Since the roots of the denominator are all real, $A, B, C$ will be real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\ 1= z^2(A+B+C) + z (\frac{-3}{2}A -2B + \frac{1}{2}C) - A$

By the [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), the two sides can only be identically equal *iff* the coefficients are pairwise equal (which is just another way to say that a polynomial is identically $0$ *iff* all its coefficients are $0\,$).

> But here is where I am confused. How do I solve for the A, B, C values when these can be complex? I thought that we could just set
>
> $\ A+B+C = 0$,
>
> $\frac{-3}{2}A -2B + \frac{1}{2}C = 0$, and
>
> $\ -A = 1$,

Yes you can do that, and that's in fact precisely how it's done.

> but I don't think this is right since z and A, B, C are complex numbers.

It *is* right, see the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
A+B+C may not be equal to zero because $z^{2}$ contain both real part or imagainary part.(eg z=i).so put z=x+iy and then solve.

Comment: Sorry, but you are plain wrong. $A+B+C$ *must* be $0$ in order for the equality to hold as a polynomial identity, regardless of whether you consider it over $\,\mathbb{C}\,$ or $\,\mathbb{R}\,$.